# Google Geocode API promise with large array

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

## My Aim

Iterate over large array using .map and query Google Geocoder API with promise.

Use Promise.all to write result to .json file on completion.

The code is written for node, the array is structured `[[key:value],[key:value],....`

---

### What I have written

```
var foo = (function() {
  let promises = airports.map(function(airport) {
    return geocoder
      .geocode(airport[1])
      .then(function(res) {
       let x = {
          ident: airport[0],
          address: res[0].formattedAddress,
          lat: res[0].latitude,
          long: res[0].longitude
        };
        return x;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function(promises) {
      console.log("promises resolved");
      fs.writeFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "/airports.json"),
        JSON.stringify(promises),
        "utf-8",
        function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Done!");
        }
      );
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
})();
```

---

### The problem

The code works fine with a small array (200 or so), but I need much more than that. I believe it is an issue with the api rate limiting as the code works fine for a few hundred iterations and then returns lots of ETIMEDOUT errors.

**Is there a way to slow down the iteration of map to say one every second, and where does that fit in with multiple promises being called?**

I think this would stop the many ETIMEDOUT errors I am getting.

Thanks.

Comment: have you searched stack overflow at all? dealing with rate limited API's has been asked and answered many times - there's even a node module called `node-rate-limiter` that may help

Comment: I understand the concept of a rate limiter, what I don't understand is where it fits in with the promises. Am I rate limiting the calling of map or the calling of geocoder?

Comment: oh, I see, sorry to have assumed you didn't search at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should limit the requests to 1 per second

```
var foo = (function() {
    var delay = 1000; // sets the rate
    return airports.reduce((promise, airport) => promise
        .then(results => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, results)))
        .then(results => geocoder
            .geocode(airport[1])
            .then(function(res) {
                let x = {
                    ident: airport[0],
                    address: res[0].formattedAddress,
                    lat: res[0].latitude,
                    long: res[0].longitude
                };
                return results.concat(x);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
        ), Promise.resolve([])
    ).then(function(promises) {
        console.log("promises resolved");
        // ... etc
    })
})();
```